# Angular5 HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, angular, angular5

Im using Angular5, and HTML5 video tag in my 'Home' component. But, the  tag its not working perfectly. So when i refresh the page the video is just stopped. If Angular rebuilding the page (after change detected), the video is started. Using simple syntax:

```
<div id="video-bg">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source [src]="videoBackgroundUrl" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Anyone with same problem? Or any fix?

Edit: Already tried with "prod" build. Live check here: http://www.resistance.nhely.hu/ If u click the bottom anchor the video is just started (lol??)

Comment: Try this: <video preload="true" autoplay muted loop>

Comment: @BharatGupta done it. Its weird, at the first load its not working still, but after if i refresh the page its working (http://www.resistance.nhely.hu/)